# Background Music Toggle (cocos2d iPhone)

Tags: iphone, background, cocos2d-iphone, toggle

I started making a toggle in my Settings scene for background music on/off. I'm not sure how to make this toggle only for background music, since I also have other effects and such in my game. How do I make the toggle only affect the background music in my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have already done so, maybe give some to you!

```
- (void)muteMusic:(CCMenuItemToggle *)sender
{
    if([[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]isBackgroundMusicPlaying])
    {
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] pauseBackgroundMusic];
    } else {
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] resumeBackgroundMusic];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to seperate my sound files from effects and background music. How do I pause ONLY the background music?

Comment: Take a look at this topic!                             http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/9914

Comment: I'm guessing cocos2d can automatically tell the difference between background music and effects? Thanks, I was misunderstanding because I forgot that playBackgroundMusic means it's not an effect or anything else. It's really confusing, but thanks for clearing that up for me. BTW I picked your answer ;)